# How to get the world coordinates of a point in a child actor?

Tags: libgdx, coordinates, scene2d

I have `Group` objects that consist of other `Group` objects, that finally consist of `Actor` objects. Now, when the groups and actors are rotated, offset and scaled, the coordinates in the "world", or in relation to the root node change. How do I get the world coordinates of a point in an actor's local space?

To illustrate a bit more, here's an example of what I want:

```
Group parentGroup;
Actor childInGroup;
...
parentGroup.addActor(childInGroup);
childInGroup.setPosition(10f, 15f);
childInGroup.setRotation(45f);

// Get the childInGroup's position in the world
float childWorldPosX = ...; // This is what I want to know
float childWorldPosY = ...; // ... and this.
```

Comment: `Actor.localToParentCoordinates()` or `Actor.localToStageCoordinates()`

Comment: @noone Thanks! Mind to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [`Actor.localToParentCoordinates()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#localToParentCoordinates%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2%29) if you want to go just one step higher in your hierarchy of `Groups` and `Actors`, or directly use [`Actor.localToStageCoordinates()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.html#localToStageCoordinates%28com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2%29) to get the "stage-global" coordinates directly. In this case, libGDX will recursively apply the `localToParentCoordinates` until it hits the root element of your stage.